# Why filename has different bytes after converting UTF16 -> UTF8 -> UTF16 in winapi?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, encoding, utf-8

I have next file:
[image]

I use [ReadDirectoryChangesW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa365465(v=vs.85).aspx) for reading changes in current folder.
And I get path to this file: L"TEST Ӡ⬨☐.ipt":

[image]

Next, I want to convert this to utf8 and back:

```
std::string wstringToUtf8(const std::wstring& source) {
  const int size = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, source.data(), static_cast<int>(source.size()), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
  std::vector<char> buffer8(size);
  WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, source.data(), static_cast<int>(source.size()), buffer8.data(), size, NULL, NULL);
}

std::wstring utf8ToWstring(const std::string& source) {
  const int size = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, source.data(), static_cast<int>(source.size()), NULL, 0);
  std::vector<wchar_t> buffer16(size);
  MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, source.data(), static_cast<int>(source.size()), buffer16.data(), size);
}

int main() {
    // Some code with ReadDirectoryChangesW and 
    // ...
    // std::wstring fileName = "L"TEST Ӡ⬨☐.ipt""
    // ...

    std::string filenameUTF8 = wstringToUtf8(fileName);
    std::wstring filename2 = utf8ToWstring(filenameUTF8);
    assert(filenameUTF8 == filename2); // FAIL!
    return 0;
}
```

But I catch assert.
filename2:
[image]

**Different bits: [29]**

Why?

Comment: For one you aren't returning your strings... And you use vector inside the function but string in the return type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

57216 seems to fall in to surrogate pair range, used in UTF-16 to encode non-BMP code points. They need to be given in pairs, or decoding won't give you correct codepoint.

65533 is a special error character which decoder gives because other surrogate is missing.

To put it another way: Your original string is not valid UTF-16 string.

[More info on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U.2BD800_to_U.2BDFFF).

Comment: The fact that the debugger draws a square for 57216 is also due to the surrogate.

Comment: It is of course possible to convert invalid surrogates to UTF-8 and back intact.  It's a little unfortunate that the Microsoft functions don't do so, because it means you can't reliably use them to encode file names.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Even though possible, surrogates (both complete and invalid) are illegal in UTF-8. So functions kind of do the right thing by not letting them through as is. But I think that best thing would have been to stop and give error code as default behaviour, and allow programmer to choose other behaviours (error char replacement or surrogate preservation) with optional flag parameters .

Comment: I suppose an optional flag would be OK, although the documentation would have to spell out very explicitly "you must use this flag when handling file names" and even then far too many programmers wouldn't read it.  There is already a flag to cause the function to fail if an invalid character is encountered, but it isn't the default.  There doesn't seem to be a flag for "make certain the conversion is reversible".

Comment: (Huh.  And prior to Windows Vista, the behaviour was exactly what I want it to be.  So the current behaviour was entirely deliberate, presumably on standards compliance grounds.)