# Is it possible to use CreateDirectoryA to create directories with asian glyphs

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to create a dir in windows with Chinese glyphs. (Project uses Multi-Byte char set)

Lets say you have the Chinese glyphs 测试 in code page 936: ²âÊÔ
Would it be possible to some how use CreateDirectoryA to create a dir in windows named: 测试

```
std::string dir936 = "H:²âÊÔ";
CreateDirectoryA(dir936.c_str(), NULL);
```

This creates a dir named H:\²âÊÔ.

Can I specify something like the locale or codepage to make this work?
Or am I required to convert to wide string and use CreateDirectoryW?

Comment: Support for multi-byte characters for Win32 is very bad. You should better switch to Unicode - it supports even Windows XP. You can find this article useful though - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx . The general problem with using CodePages is that your source-files are bound to some specific code-page unless you write your strings with hex characters which is not the best option. So then if someone needs to use your source files it would need to switch to the code page that you are using (at least with VS).

Comment: No, I don't think so, and definitely not unless your system locale is set to such that supports these symbols and your dir name is encoded with teh same locale. Why not use `CreateDirectoryW`?

Comment: Unless you have to support some ancient version of Windows, why wouldn't you use Unicode? It's 2016, not 1995.

Comment: Please read: http://utf8everywhere.org/ (10 How to do text on Windows)

Comment: @DieterLücking: worth reading, but some of it needs to be taken with a grain of salt.  In particular, converting from UTF-16 to UTF-8 and back to use the API needs to be done with greater care: as of Vista, the MultiByteToWideChar and WideCharToMultibyte functions are lossy.  I think other strictly-standards-conforming functions will too.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/34743801/886887 for example.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I was curious to see if it was possible at all but seams that I will be using CreateDirectoryW. Unfortunately using Unicode is not an option at the moment. Thanks for the input and the links to the articles, will give them a read.